# Why gitosis init sequence fails?

Tags: git, gitosis

After I run the `init` command, I see the following error message:

```
  -sh-4.1$ gitosis-init <id_rsa_git.pub 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gitosis-init", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gitosis==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'gitosis-init')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 24, in run
    return app.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 38, in main
    self.handle_args(parser, cfg, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 123, in handle_args
    user = ssh_extract_user(pubkey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 39, in ssh_extract_user
    raise InsecureSSHKeyUsername(repr(user))
gitosis.init.InsecureSSHKeyUsername: Username contains not allowed characters: 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAwCDbFIFqHKMwruJiktoSrErfA0bymw78HOWPSyIdEo2K9krTc7Xa6LOrn/BlSJflw4pd1cKvbl4YIxfKiNRsJDHBV/g0h6iN3cLgWnJ/DIQ3OhG  ------------the public key other
```

How would you troubleshoot this gitosis initialization sequence?

Comment: Note to moderators: gitosis/gitolite questions are perfectly valid on Stack Overflow. Just beccause you don't have experience in this tool doesn't mean you *have* to close the question. You can edit it instead.

Comment: There is a difference between moderators and users who vote to close. But we can't expect users who have that much rep and that many years on the site to know the difference @von

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm  solve the question
 change the publish key with the  format,add the name and server  begin the key

```
ssh-rsa git@yourdomain.com
AAAAB3NzaC1yc........................etc
~
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create your git ssh keys with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "path/to/id_rsa_git" -C "gitosis admin key" -q -P ""
```

That would work too for [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) key. -And you *really* should use gitolite. Gitosis is obsolete since 2009)